# Large Pearson residuals

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals, large-data, contingency-tables, correspondence-analysis

My aim is to see if there exists a relation between the variables "Category" and "Types", spec. if there is a tendency for a particular category to use a particular type. These are the observed frequencies:

|  | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 800 | 1 | 9 | 245 | 2503 |
| B | 350 | 1560 | 1200 | 341 | 790 |
| C | 7 | 290 | 7 | 607 | 1 |
| D | 387 | 1001 | 1311 | 932 | 598 |
| E | 16 | 81 | 19 | 7 | 4 |
| F | 493 | 98 | 0 | 39 | 342 |
| G | 32 | 318 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| H | 777 | 52 | 18 | 127 | 139 |
| I | 3 | 2 | 27 | 9 | 1 |
| J | 128 | 299 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| K | 10 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 76 |
| L | 139 | 1 | 1 | 29 | 6 |

So I conducted a chi-square test. This is the code I used in R:

```r
x <- matrix(c(800, 350, 7, 387, 16, 493, 32, 777, 
    3, 128, 10, 139, 10, 1560, 290, 1001, 81, 98, 
    318, 52, 4, 299, 15, 18, 19, 1200, 7, 1311, 
    19, 0, 2, 18, 27, 10, 2, 8, 245, 341, 607, 
    932, 7, 39, 10, 127, 9, 7, 8, 29, 2503, 790, 
    1, 598, 4, 342, 3, 139, 2, 3, 76, 6), ncol=5)

attr(x, "dimnames") <- list(Category=c("A", "B", 
    "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", 
    "L"), 
    Types = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5"))

x.test <- chisq.test(x, correct = FALSE)

x.test$expected
```

All the expected frequencies are > 5 and the result of the chi-square test is: X-squared = 13493, df = 44, p-value < 2.2e-16. I have also used Cramer's V to see how strong is the effect independently of the sample size (Cramer's V = 0.4543752).

I have also calculated Pearson and standardized residuals (It's not clear to me what should I use, if any) but the values are very large and I have read that this may indicate large errors, which may imply that the model can be inappropriate for the data.

These are the results of Pearson residuals:

[image]

And these are the results for standardized residuals:

[image]

Does it make any sense or would it be better to use another measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a large contingency table with large counts you are better off with visualizing methods, or simply reordering rows/columns of the table so that structure becomes more easily visible. The large chi-squared value, and large residuals makes it apparent that the independence model is untrue.

Correspondence analysis is your help. Some code in R, with your data:

```r
mod.CA <- MASS::corresp(x, nf=2)
plot(mod.CA)   ### A biplot (not shown here)
```

I will use the row and column scores corresponding to the largest eigenvalue to reorder rows and columns, then the structure will be more visible:

```r
RS <- mod.CA$rscore[, 1]
CS <- mod.CA$cscore[, 1]

X <- x[order(RS), order(CS)]

X
        Types
Category   T5  T1  T4   T3   T2
       A 2503 800 245   19   10
       F  342 493  39    0   98
       H  139 777 127   18   52
       K   76  10   8    2   15
       L    6 139  29    8   18
       B  790 350 341 1200 1560
       J    3 128   7   10  299
       D  598 387 932 1311 1001
       E    4  16   7   19   81
       I    2   3   9   27    4
       C    1   7 607    7  290
       G    3  32  10    2  318
```

We can also show the table as a mosaicplot:

```r
mosaicplot(X, color=TRUE)
```

[image: Mosaicplot of table]